# undefined method `page' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xaadc8d4>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari, pagination

Im trying to install Kaminari pagination on rails 3 with adminpanel RailsAdmin, but I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in ShowsController#
undefined method `page' for # < ActiveRecord::Relation:0xaadc8d4>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you also have the gem "will_paginate" in use?

Check the file Gemfile.lock to see if you have this gem in use as well:

```
grep will_paginate Gemfile.lock
```

If that's the case, all you have to do is to create the file "config/initializers/kaminari.rb" and write this content on the file:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

that should fix the issue

Comment: An is still fixing it in 2018. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to add the `kaminari` gem to my `Gemfile` :facepalm: